# Pull type-level value out of dependent type/using type-level bindings at value-level

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, gadt, data-kinds

When I have a dependent type in Haskell, how do I use the value stored in the type in a function? Example Haskell program that I would want to write (which **does not compile**, because the `min` and `max` typelevel bindings do not extend to value level):

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
module CharRange (CharRange, ofChar, asChar) where

data CharRange :: Char -> Char -> * where
  C :: Char -> CharRange min max

ofChar :: Char -> CharRange min max
ofChar c =
  if min <= c && c <= max
  then C c
  else C min

asChar :: CharRange min max -> Char
asChar (C c) =
  if min <= c && c <= max
  then c
  else min
```

I can do this in Idris:

```
module CharRange

%default total
%access export

data CharRange : Char -> Char -> Type where
  C : Char -> CharRange min max

ofChar : Char -> CharRange min max
ofChar c =
  if min <= c && c <= max
  then C c
  else C min

asChar : CharRange min max -> Char
asChar (C c) =
  if min <= c && c <= max
  then c
  else min
```

Which compiles and works as expected:

```
λΠ> the (CharRange 'a' 'z') $ ofChar 'M'
C 'a' : CharRange 'a' 'z'
λΠ> the (CharRange 'a' 'z') $ ofChar 'm'
C 'm' : CharRange 'a' 'z'
```

How do I translate this Idris program to Haskell without reducing the amount of information in the type?

Comment: Haskell doesn't have dependent types.

Comment: To expand on @chepner’s comment: You can definitely _simulate_ dependent types using libraries like `singletons`, and by using various language features. However, Haskell doesn’t (yet) support dependent types themselves, so even though you can get quite close to using them, you can’t actually use dependent types in the same way you’re trying to use them.

Comment: The type `Char` contains no types (though it does contain many values). That is, it is currently not useful to write `data CharRange :: Char -> Char -> Type` (BTW, `*` is deprecated, please use `Type` from `Data.Kind`), because you can never actually construct the type `CharRange x y` for some `x, y :: Char`. `DataKinds` basically works only for ADTs, plus the (unbearably wonky, IMO) built-ins `Nat` and `Symbol`.

Comment: @HTNW "The type `Char` contains no types (though it does contain many values)"...rather, "The kind `Char` contains no types (though the type `Char` does contain many values)", right?

Comment: No, it's the same `Char` on both sides. Values have types. Types have types. It's a historical accident that we sometimes say the word "kind", because there used to be difference, and now there isn't. `Char` is an example of a type that's full of values but devoid of types. `Type` is an example of a type that's devoid of values and full of types. Most types are the same on both sides.

Comment: In Haskell, when we write `ofChar : forall min max .  .....etc etc` the type-level arguments `min` and `max` are used during type-checking, and then _erased_ at runtime (unlike Idris). This means that `ofChar`, at runtime, receives no information about what `min` and `max` are. To circumvent that, we usually resort to `singletons`, and write something like `ofChar :: forall min max . SChar min -> SChar max -> ....etc etc` where `SChar c` is a "singleton" type which preserves, at run-time, the information that would be lost. You'll find many examples in the `singletons` library.

Comment: @chi my understanding was that in Idris, they were erased as well.

Comment: @KeithPinson I don't know Idris very well, but if they are erased, how can `min < c` be computed at runtime? That test requires to have `min` available at runtime, somewhere.

Comment: @chi I've always assumed there was some kind of defunctionalization or something going on. I honestly don't know much about the implementation. But maybe I'm [wrong](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/wiki/Egg-%232%3A-Erasure-annotations).

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Right now, I think that erasure in Idris can be performed in certain cases, but not always. If you explicitly use `min` in your function, I can't see how that can be erased. If `min` only appears on types as an index, and its value has no direct effect on running the code, then it can be erased, I think. "Proofs" can be erased, but data can not. [This](https://idris.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/erasure.html#changes-to-idris) clarifies a bit what Idris does, and indeed it claims it erases the "things" which are not "being used" / do not affect run-time behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility (however I am not convinced it is worth the trouble) is to index your `CharRange` with `Nat`ural numbers rather than the `Char` they encode.

This way you get use [`GHC.TypeNats`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/GHC-TypeNats.html) to gain the ability to obtain a copy of these type levels bounds.

The worked out solution goes something like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

module Ranged (CharRange, ofChar, asChar) where

import GHC.TypeNats
import Data.Char
import Data.Proxy

data CharRange :: Nat -> Nat -> * where
  C :: Char -> CharRange min max

ofChar :: forall min max. (KnownNat min, KnownNat max)
       => Char -> CharRange min max
ofChar c =
  let min = fromIntegral $ natVal (Proxy :: Proxy min) in
  let max = fromIntegral $ natVal (Proxy :: Proxy max) in
  if min <= fromEnum c && fromEnum c <= max
  then C c
  else C (toEnum min)

asChar :: forall min max. (KnownNat min, KnownNat max)
       => CharRange min max -> Char
asChar (C c) =
  let min = fromIntegral $ natVal (Proxy :: Proxy min) in
  let max = fromIntegral $ natVal (Proxy :: Proxy max) in
  if min <= fromEnum c && fromEnum c <= max
  then c
  else toEnum min
```

Comment: Appreciate both the option and the "not convinced it is worth the trouble".

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to do any fancy arithmetic on the bounds, but use them as configurable constants, enforcing an invariant throughout a computation, you can also use the reflection package.

The upside is that your constants do not have to be known at compile time. Have a look at the documentation for the [reflection package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection-2.1.5/docs/Data-Reflection.html) to learn more. For example, there is an instance `KnownNat n => Reifies (n :: Nat) Integer` so there is some interoperability (in one direction, at least), e.g. using `reifyNat` instead of `reify` to configure your terms.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, TypeApplications, FlexibleContexts -#}
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
import Data.Reflection
import Data.Char
import Data.Proxy

newtype CharRange min max = C Char

--| this is the only thing that needs AllowAmbiguousTypes, but we don't need to write
-- Proxy everywhere. Choose your poison.
reflect' :: forall s a. Reifies s a => a
reflect' = reflect @s Proxy

ofChar :: forall min max. (Reifies min Char, Reifies max Char)
       => Char -> CharRange min max
ofChar c =
  if reflect' @min <= c && c <= reflect' @max
  then C c
  else C $ reflect' @min

asChar :: forall min max. (Reifies min Char, Reifies max Char)
       => CharRange min max -> Char
asChar (C c) =
  if reflect' @min <= c && c <= reflect' @max
  then c
  else reflect' @min

-- At the toplevel, you need to configure your 'constants'.
-- using reify you get Proxy parameters, that allows you to capture
-- the type variable that is used to reflect the arguments back inside
-- your computation.
-- this might seem like a lot of code, but since it's toplevel needs only
-- be done once.
main = print $ show $ reify 'a' $
            \(_ :: Proxy min) -> reify 'z' $
              \(_ :: Proxy max) -> asChar (ofChar @min @max '_')
```